# Find the sum to $n$ terms of the series of series $2+0+7-4+21-26+71-...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question**:-Find the sum to $n$ terms of the series of series $2+0+7-4+21-26+71-...$

I found this question on a blog.It looks difficult to find general term of the series.After finding the general term it is easy to evaluate the sum.

Can anybody help me to find the general term of the series!

Comment: The problem with this question is: there is not enough information.  Given finitely many terms of a sequence, say $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k$, you can always find a logical argument to show that $a_{k+1}$ can be any number you wish.  For example, if I give you $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$,  $11$, and $x$, then you might think a sequence of primes so that $x=13$.  However, you might also think that this is a sequence of [partition function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) values $p(n)$ with $n>1$, so $x=p(7)=15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the solution of @Martund the second differences are in GP with common ration $(-2)$, then $n$th term willbe opthe tupe $T(n)=An+B+C 2^n$, then $$T(1)=A+B-2C=2,T(2)=2A+B+4C=-, T(3)=3A+B-8C=7$$. Solving these equations, we get $a=1,b=0,c=-1/2$, So $$T(k)=k+(-2)^{k-1}$$
THen $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k+ (-2)^{k-1}= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(-2)^n-1}{3}$$

Answer (score 4):

\begin{matrix}
2&&0&&7&&-4&&21&&-26&&71\\
&-2&&7&&-11&&25&&-47&&97\\
&&9&&-18&&36&&-72&&144
\end{matrix}
Above are the differences and double differences of terms of this sequence. The sequence in last row is $9(-2)^{n-1}$. Can you proceed now?

Comment: Thanks, So the general term is $n+(-2)^{(n-1)}$